# keyWindow positions are "half as big" bizarre issue

Tags: ios, uiview, segue, addsubview

If you want to move a UIView from one view to another (say, "transferring" a UIView through a segue), this works perfectly ...

```
-(void)takeover:(UIView*)peel
    {
    // transfer "ownership" of a view from wherever it is now, to self.
    // keep the position correct.

    CGPoint centerInWC = [peel.superview convertPoint:peel.center toView:nil];
    [self addSubview:peel];
    CGPoint centerInMyViewCoords = [self convertPoint:centerInWC fromView:nil];
    peel.center = centerInMyViewCoords;
    }
```

(Note from the documentation for toView: and fromView: ... `"If view is nil, this method instead converts to window base coordinates."`)

Here's the output ..

```
2014-07-07 19:59:04.273  before .... actual position ... {87, 107}
2014-07-07 19:59:04.278  centerInWC is ... {87, 107}
2014-07-07 19:59:04.278  centerInMyViewCoords is ... {87, 107}
```

No problem. Everything's fantastic.

What about using **the main window, so keyWindow** ??

Now, you'd THINK that the following would also work:

```
-(void)takeover:(UIView*)peel
    {
    //let's try using "main window" coords...

    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    CGPoint cWC = [mainWindow convertPoint:peel.center fromView:peel.superview];
    [self addSubview:peel];
    CGPoint c = [self convertPoint:cWC fromView:mainWindow];
    peel.center = c;
    }
```

In fact it does not work!

Every single time, you get values that are **one half** the actual, correct values.

Here's the output...

```
2014-07-07 19:59:04.273  before .... actual position ... {87, 107}
2014-07-07 19:59:04.278  cWC is ... {43.5, 53.5}
2014-07-07 19:59:04.278  c is ... {43.5, 53.5}
```

Anyone know the explanation?  Cheers...

Comment: Are you testing on a retina device? I think you may need to take   `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` into account

Comment: I was indeed testing on a normal retina device, not a museum piece! :)  It's the same in the simulator, too.  It seems damned weird that the scale would be "single" on .keyWindow don't you think?  I guess someone will have to dig up an old machine and test it ... there's no "half res" simulator anymore  :/